# In Gtk+ 3.x, how to add line-height to multi-line text label?

Tags: python, gtk3

There's a word-wrapped, multi-line text label in a Python-based Gtk+ 3 GUI application.

```
    label = Gtk.Label(
        "Long text. Long text. Long text. " +
        "Long text. Long text. Long text. " +
        "Long text. Long text. Long text. " +
        "Long text. Long text. Long text. " +
        "Long text. Long text. Long text. " +
        "Long text. Long text. Long text. " +
        "Long text. Long text. Long text.",
        halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER,
        valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER,
        vexpand = True,
        margin_left = 20,
        margin_right = 20
    )
    label.set_line_wrap(True)
    grid.add(label)
```

The GUI mock up wants the text to use additional spacing between the lines of the label. In CSS, that would be done with the "line-height" property, but is it possible to implement this in Gtk+ 3?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with `Gtk.Label` and CSS currently. You can use a `Gtk.TextView` and apply a `Gtk.TextTag` with the [`pixels_inside_wrap`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/TextTag.html#Gtk.TextTag.props.pixels_inside_wrap) property set.